# cannot access attribute in table with many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two tables set up in a many to many relationship: maintenance_schedule and service_type. I'm trying to make a dropdown list on the form for maintenance_schedule that allows me to select service_type_name from the service_type table.

My models are set up like this:

```
class ServiceType < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :service_type_name
    has_many :maintenance_schedules, :through =>  :schedule_services
end

class MaintenanceSchedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :maintenance_schedule_date
    has_many :service_types, :through => :schedule_services
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_types
end

class ScheduleService < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :maintenance_schedule_id, :service_type_id
    belongs_to :maintenance_schedule
    belongs_to :service_type
end
```

my index page is giving me undefined method `service_type_name'

```
<p id=<%="maintenance_schedule_#{maintenance_schedule.id}"%>>
<div>service type: <%=  maintenance_schedule.service_types.service_type_name %></div>
<%= link_to "Delete", maintenance_schedule_path(maintenance_schedule.id), :method => :delete, :class => "delete", :confirm => "Are you so sure?"%>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_maintenance_schedule_path(maintenance_schedule)%>
```

This is my index method in the controller

```
def index
@maintenance_schedules = MaintenanceSchedule.all

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @maintenance_schedules}
end
end
```

Comment: Try `:service_type_ids` instead.

Comment: Now I'm getting undefined method `sevice_type_name

Comment: sevice_type_name is a typo I assume.

Comment: haha it was a typo. I'm getting another error though `Could not find the association :schedule_services in model MaintenanceSchedule`

Comment: Where do you define the schedule_services association?  I don't see it able.  Presumably you should have a 'has_many :schedule_services' on MaintenanceSchedule.

Comment: adding the has_many :schedule_services to got it to work when I go to maintenance_schedules/new, but not the index page where I'm using jquery to render it.

`<p id=<%="maintenance_schedule_#{maintenance_schedule.id}"%>>
<div>service type: <%= maintenance_schedule.service_types.service_type_name %></div>
<%= link_to "Delete", maintenance_schedule_path(maintenance_schedule.id), :method => :delete, :class => "delete", :confirm => "Are you so sure?"%>
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_maintenance_schedule_path(maintenance_schedule)%>
</p>`